# How Enter key behaves for a textbox in the IWindowsFormsEditorService.DropDownControl(userControl)

Tags: c#, propertygrid, design-time, uitypeeditor

I have a custom control with a property Value.

The `property grid` displays the editor in the `dropdown style`, using the `IWindowsFormsEditorService.DropDownControl(userControl)` method within the

```
MyUITypeEditor.EditValue(...).
```

The drop down editor has a text box that displays the value.

The entered text is validated in the event handler for `Validating` event. With this, when enter some text and press `Enter key`, the dropdown does not close down.

However, if along with `Validaing` event, I hook onto `TextChanged` event, then when I hit enter the dropdown closes.

In the editor code, i dont have any code to handle the Enter key.

I am wondering how the `DropDownControl(...)` internally works by handling the Enter key.

Any explanation is most welcome.

Thanks